# RSTP sending BPDUs out of the network switch?

Tags: ethernet, spanning-tree, ieee-802.1w

I need some information about RSTP

If the port state is blocking, discarding alternate .

Should BPDU be sent to external ports? I cant see any BPDU in wireshark if the port states Alternate,Discarding mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, for a device to be on-topic here, the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support. Your custom-built network switch is off-topic. We have not idea about it.

Comment: not about custom switch it is a RSTP network protocole rule !

Comment: BPDUs are sent out all ports except edge ports.

Comment: If my port state discarding , is that port send BPDU out of port ? Should I see on wireshark that BPDU ?

Comment: Yes.  To repeat, BPDUs are sent out all ports except edge ports.

Comment: Thats huge problem  my swtich does not send bpdu discarding state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the switches in network intially sends and receives BPDU messages when connected in network and election process starts . Switch Ports  enters blocking state during the time of election process, when a switch receives a BPDU on a port that indicates a better path to the Root Switch Root Bridge and if a port is not a Root Port or a Designated Port.

The  port in the blocking state does not participate in sending any BPDU message it's only in listene for BPDU messages nor it does not  sends frame forwarding and also discards frames received from the attached network segment. During blocking state, the port is only listening to and processing BPDUs on its interfaces. After 20 seconds, the switch port will  changes its state from blocking state to  listening state.